# Mongodb: Restoring database produces this error E11000 duplicate key error collection: DATABASE_NAME.users index: _id_ dup key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I dumped my database using this command:

> mongodump --uri
> 'mongodb+srv://ACCOUNT_NAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/DATABASE_NAME' --archive="DATABASE_DUMP" --forceTableScan

Then I tried to restore it using this:

> mongorestore --uri
> 'mongodb+srv://ACCOUNT_NAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/DATABASE_NAME' --archive="DATABASE_DUMP" --nsFrom='DATABASE_NAME.*' --nsTo='DATABASE_NAME_COPY.*'

But, this is what gets logged for **each collection**:

> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.359+0000    restoring to existing collection
> DATABASE_NAME.admins without dropping
>
> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.359+0000    restoring DATABASE_NAME.admins from archive
> 'DATABASE_DUMP'
>
> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.464+0000    continuing through error: E11000
> duplicate key error collection: .admins index: *id* dup key: {
> _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') }
>
> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.464+0000    continuing through error: E11000
> duplicate key error collection: DATABASE_NAME.admins index: *id* dup key: {
> _id: ObjectId('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy') }
>
> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.464+0000    finished restoring DATABASE_NAME.admins (0
> documents, 2 failures)

And in the end this is what gets logged:

> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.567+0000    no indexes to restore for collection
> DATABASE_NAME.admins
>
> 2021-11-28T13:28:48.664+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully.
> 152793 document(s) failed to restore.

I usually dump and restore without any problem. So I have no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you hit duplications(E11000) because you load same documents to the already existing ...
If you add --drop to the mongorestore it will drop the previous collections and restore only the documents from the backup

Comment: Whatdo you mean 'load same documents to the already existing'. I am trying to create a brand new database from the one I dumped. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ah interesting , can you try restoring wothout auto index creation ?

Comment: R2D2: to restore without index you can use mongorestore --noIndexRestore

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem, I'm restoring a big collection with --drop option and --noIndexRestore and getting loads of E11000 errors. How is that possible?